# Make docker image as base for another image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Now I have built a simple GET API to access this database: https://github.com/ghusta/docker-postgres-world-db

This API will get a country code and get the full record of the country of this country from the database.

The structure is that the API is in a separate docker image, and the database is in another one.

So once the API's image tries to start, I need it to start the database's image before and then start running itself upon the database's image.

So how to do that?

Comment: You can use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Docker Compose, specifically the [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) directive. This will cause Docker to start all dependencies before starting an image.

Unfortunately there is no way to make it wait for the dependency to go live before starting any dependents. You'll have to manage that yourself with a wait script or similar.

Comment: The useful application of `depends_on:` is that `docker-compose up webapp` will also start its dependent containers, but if the database initialization takes any length of time it's highly likely the application will start first and will need to detect or recover from this in some way.

Answer (score 2):

A most probable solution would be to use docker compose along with a third party script.

For Example your docker compose file might look like:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Where   `./wait-for-it.sh` is a third party script you can get from

https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

You can also use this script from

https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for

I would recommend to tweak the script as per your needs if you want to(i did that).

P.S:

The problem of waiting for a database (for example) to be ready is really just a subset of a much larger problem of distributed systems. In production, your database could become unavailable or move hosts at any time. Your application needs to be resilient to these types of failures.

To handle this, design your application to attempt to re-establish a connection to the database after a failure. If the application retries the connection, it can eventually connect to the database.

The best solution is to perform this check in your application code, both at startup and whenever a connection is lost for any reason